# Inverse sublist

Tags: prolog

I have written code of inverse sublist

```
minv([],_,_,[]).
minv(L,N,K,Result):-
   slist(0,N-1,L,Re1),
   append(Re1,[],Result1),
   slist(N-1,K-N+1,L,Re),
   reverse(Re,Res),
   append(Result1,Res,Result2),
   length(L,D),
   slist(K,D-K,L,Resu),
   append(Result2,Resu,Result).


slist(0,0,_,[]):-!.
slist(0,Length,[E|List],[E|Sublist]):-
   Length1 is Length-1,!,
   slist(0,Length1,List,Sublist).
slist(Offset,Length,[_|List],Sublist):-
   Offset1 is Offset-1,!,
   slist(Offset1,Length,List,Sublist).
```

But teacher sad it's not prolog style, because minv so bad. Please help

Answer (score 2):

It took me sometime to understand that minv means my inverse.
You just take elements from the input list and append them at the end of the result list.

```
inverse([], []).
inverse([H|T], Result):-
    inverse(T, TInv), append(TInv, [H], Result).
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not simple reverse as mentioned in the answer by George. minv(List, Begin, End, Result) takes the sublist from Begin to End and reverses that portion only.

| ?- minv([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],2,3,X).

X = [1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,9] ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try: (I didn't test it on prolog)

```
inverse(L, 1, 1, L).

inverse([H|L], 1, K, [H|R]):-
    inverse(L, 1, K-1, LInv), append(LInv, [H], R).

inverse([H|L], N, K, [H|R]):-
    inverse(L, N-1, K, R).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inverse(L,Begin,End,Result) :-
        length(L1,End),
        Begin_1 is Begin - 1,
        length(L0,Begin_1),
        append(L0,L2,L1),
        append(L1,L3,L),
        reverse(L2,RL2),
        append(L0,RL2,L3,Result).
```